# How to pass data forward between View Controllers - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, viewcontroller

Hi I would like to know why every-time i ask for the emailCatched value in the second VC, I always get nil. Isn't how you pass data forward? Sorry if it's very basic.
I wrote the same code for passing the password from VC2 to  VC3 and it works, it's weird. Thanks

First VC :

```
   class EmailAddressViewController: UIViewController {
  
    
    let emailField: UITextField = {
        let emailField = UITextField()
 
        return emailField
    }()
    
    
    private let continueButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        return button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        // SubViews
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(emailField)
        view.addSubview(continueButton)      
        
   // I omitted the frames
       
        continueButton.addTarget(self,
                                 action: #selector(continueButtonTapped),
                                 for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func continueButtonTapped() { 
        
        let email = emailField.text,
             
        let vc = PasswordViewController()
        vc.emailCatched = email
        self.present(PasswordViewController(), animated: true)     
    }    
}
```

Second VC (PasswordViewController) :

```
class PasswordViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    private let passwordField: UITextField = {
        let passwordField = UITextField()
        passwordField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        passwordField.autocorrectionType = .no
        passwordField.returnKeyType = .next
        passwordField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        passwordField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        passwordField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        passwordField.placeholder = "Mot de passe"
        passwordField.textAlignment = .center
        passwordField.backgroundColor = .white
        passwordField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return passwordField
    }()
    
    private let continueButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Continuer", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    var emailCatched: String?
    
    // MARK: viewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print(emailCatched!) // returns error or nil
        
        // SubViews
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(passwordField)
        view.addSubview(continueButton)
        
        
       
       
        continueButton.addTarget(self,
                                 action: #selector(continueButtonTapped),
                                 for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
      
        
    }
    
    
  
  
    
    // function bouton continuer
    @objc private func continueButtonTapped() {
        
        passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        guard let password = passwordField.text,
              !password.isEmpty,
              password.count >= 8 else {
            alertInvalidPassword()
            return
        }
        let vc = NamesViewController()
       // vc.emailCatched = emailCatched!
        vc.passwordCatched = password
        HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
        self.presenter(vc, animated: false, pushing: true, completion: nil)
    }
   
    
}
```

Comment: Thats not right. Check this: https://iosarchitect.com/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift/

Comment: The reason you're getting a `nil` in your second VC is that in your first VC you are creating an unreferenced new instance of the `PasswordViewController` class and setting its property, which is not changing the one that's already instantiated.

Comment: In order for it to work, you'll need to create a reference for your already-instantiated VC and modify the property via that reference. Could you please show more code?

Comment: @AgentBilly I'm not using storyboards. How do I create a reference of the PasswordViewController() for example? Thanks

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com I'm not using storyboards.. How could I do it?

Comment: @bigip If you instantiated your password VC the way you did in your edited code and pushed that specific instance, then it should have no problem updating the property. To help you further, how did you pushed the password VC and how (where) did you try to access the property?

Comment: @AgentBilly I updated the post, does it help? I don't have any idea how to fix this. Thank you

Comment: @bigip the issue is with this line: `self.present(PasswordViewController(), animated: true)`, again, you presented a new instance of the class instead of the one you've already instantiated (`vc`), try replacing it with `self.present(vc, animated: true)` and see if it works now.

Comment: @AgentBilly it works. I love you

Comment: @bigip Glad that I could help! :P